# iOS - Supporting Multiple Apps With Same Version And Content But Different App Name And Bundle ID

Tags: ios, xcode

We developed an app for our client and it is now available in the app store. Lets call it the **MAIN APP** here.

Now the client wants a separate version of that app, without changing anything but just the name of the **MAIN APP**. Let's call it the **ALT APP** here.

The **MAIN APP** has two Xcode projects, one is the older one, the other is the latest, which is the one what I am working on with new features. 
I uploaded the first version of the **ALT APP** before by changing the app name and bundle ID of the older project of the **MAIN APP**. So you can think of it that the older project of the **MAIN APP** is now the project of the **ALT APP**

Now I need to update the features of the **ALT APP** to the same as the **MAIN APP**.

One way to do this is to copy paste the source files of the **MAIN APP** and overwrite it to the source files of the **ALT APP** but I think this takes time.

The other way I thought of is to just change the app name and bundle ID of the latest project of the **MAIN APP**, upload the **ALT APP** and then later on change it back when I need to upload the **MAIN APP**

But I am afraid that if I kept on changing the bundle ID there will be build problems(although I haven't encountered any yet).

Is there any better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One project, two targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make One Project.
2. Go to Project setting -> Build Setting
3. Change
   [Current Project Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz2CB.png)
   As you want.
4. [Duplicate your 'base' target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI1R1.png) as you want
5. Go to Target -> General -> Version
   and Write $(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)
6. Change bundle identifier.
7. Go to Target -> Info and find 'Bundle name' and change it. That will be your app name.

I wish you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like you need to look into branching in your source code repository. Git in particular is suited to pulling individual commits between branches. Thus allowing you to select changes to copy. Providing you are careful about what you are committing.

Ultimately it sounds like your project is going to end up being an old code based with patches and a new code base with new features. Perhaps your client is not clear enough about what they want. Keeping two version of an app current in the app store would be a headache. Far better to retire one and move with the new.